# Drawing perpendicular lines in between two paths

Tags: adobe-illustrator, autocad, illustrator-cs6

I am an architect working in ancient sites for architectural documentation. I am now trying to make an oldschool landscape drawing, which includes the height curves. (contour lines)

So for that, I am trying to drawing perpendicular lines arrayed along one line, starting from it and ending at the next one. which, i need to do it atleast 750 lines.

so to sum up, I want to fill the gap in between two lines with lines which are perpendicular to the path they are starting from and ending at the next one.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: how can i draw these lines?

Comment: I think that this question is off topic here. http://superuser.com/help/on-topic You will get more answers if you ask in the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, you want to draw something like a stairs. I will assume that one of the lines has an equation

```
a x + b y + c = 0
```

with nonzero `a` and `b` (special cases `a=0` or `b=0` are trivial). I will also assume that `a^2+b^2=1` (if not, just divide the equation by `1/sqrt(a^2+b^2)`).

Then if have the lengths of your lines `L`, and the coordinate of starting point is `(x0,y0)`, then coordinates of other points, where perpendicular lines start are

```
(x_i, y_i) = ( x0 + (b L i)/(N-1), y0 - (a L i)/(N-1) )
```

where `i` runs fro `0` to `N-1`, and `N` is the number of points, that you need for your staircase.

Note: if points will go in the wrong direction, use the opposite sign

```
(x_i, y_i) = ( x0 - (b L i)/(N-1), y0 + (a L i)/(N-1) )
```

After you have points, where the perpendicular lines start, the parametric equations for each perpendicular line is

```
x_i(t) = x_i + a t D, y_i(t) = y_i + b t D
```

where `t` changes from `0` to `1` and `D` is the distance between your parallel lines.

Note: if perpendicular lines go to the wrong direction, change sign

```
x_i(t) = x_i - a t D, y_i(t) = y_i - b t D
```

That is more or less it)

Comment: and what if you are dealing with a wavy stair case instead of a circular or straight one?